# regex pattern isn't working in input Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, regex, validation, input

```
pattern="[a-zA-Z ]*"
```

im trying to limit the input to be only letters no numbers or symbols should be allowed

but the given code is not working

```
  <input
                name="cardName"
                type="text"
                required 
                pattern="[a-zA-Z ]*"
                defaultValue={kardName}
/>
```

i have also tried to use onChange method but it wasn't working too

anyhelp would be highly apperciated

Comment: i have tried this just now but unfortunately it gave me the same result, it allows numbers + letters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pattern` attribute specifies a regular expression that the  element's value is checked against on form submission.

You can see from the snippet below, that if you hit submit, the pattern is checked and it's actually working.

```html
<form>
    <input
      name="cardName"
      type="text"
      required 
      pattern="[a-zA-Z ]*"
    />
    <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```

If you want to prevent the user from inserting some character, the pattern attribute won't help you.

What You can do is check the character inside the `onKeyDown` function, and prevent the insertion there. Something like this:

```
const onKeyDown = (event) => {
if (!event.key.match(/[A-Za-z ]/)) {
  event.preventDefault()
}

...

  <input
    name="cardName"
    type="text"
    required
    onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
  />
```

Comment: can i use same method for only numbers? i will change the regex to ^0*\d{1,3}$

Comment: Sure, you can use whatever regex you like